# Printing Next Item in Python For Loop

Tags: python

I have this bit of code:

```
corpus = "T1T2T3"

for character in corpus:
    if character == 'T':
        print character + corpus[corpus.index(character) + 1]
```

I would simply like to print all of the T's and the letters that follow. In this case, it should print T1 T2 T3 --  instead only T1 T1 T1 is being printed. Any idea what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the index in your iteration using the `enumerate` function:

```
for index, character in enumerate(corpus):
    if character == 'T':
        print character + corpus[index + 1]
```

Alternately, you can use a *regular expression* to look for the pattern you want:

```
import re

for match in re.findall('T.', corpus): # a . in the regular expression pattern means "match any character"
    print match
```

Comment: Perfect task for regex

Comment: Thanks -- helped me out a lot!

Answer (score 1):

When you do `corpus.index(character)` , it will always find the index of the first occurence of `character` , so it would always return `0`.

You can instead use `enumerate()` to get the index as well when you iterate over the string. Example -

```
corpus = "T1T2T3"

for idx, character in enumerate(corpus):
    if character == 'T' and (idx + 1) < len(corpus):
        print character + corpus[idx + 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

string.index gets you only the *first* occurrence of the character in the string.  You can specify which occurrence number you want; you would have to maintain this.

Alternately, perhaps something like this is what you have in mind, stepping through by the index.

```
for char_pos in len(corpus):
    if corpus[char_pos] == 'T':
        print corpus[char_pos:char_pos+2]
```